# Access 2010: Is there a way to create a password protected form/button?

Tags: password-protection, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to create a password protected form or button in access 2010?

I tried this one (http://technologytraining.psu.edu/node/728) but when I give a wrong password, it stills working.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my question! @HansUp thank you for your help!
I hadn't enabled the controls.

```
  Private Sub MyButton_Click()
      Const cstrPassWord As String = "open"
      Dim strPassWord As String
      strPassWord = InputBox("Password:")
      If strPassWord = cstrPassWord Then
            Forms!Pharmacy.Form!pharmacy_warehouse_stock_Subform.Form!delete_query_button.Enabled = True

     Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect password."
     End If
  End Sub
```